# How to make curved Tabs in TabBar in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

How can i make curved Tabs Like this image have ?
[Tabs Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCaeH.png)

Here is my code that i tried :

```
TabBar(
    controller: _tabcntrl,
    indicatorColor: Colors.white,
    indicator: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
    indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
    labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
    tabs: <Widget>[
        DecoratedBox(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))),
              child: FlatButton(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 80,
                  child: Text(
                    'Expense',
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
```

I tried giving radius to box of FlatButton but it didnt work.

Comment: do you also want a curve from bottom as can be shown from image or curve inside for that you can use borderRadius property of indicator.

Comment: Hi thanks it did worked. any more suggestion on how to make that curve between tab and its container ?

Comment: Please add something more what exactly you want. I am not able to understand what you want more now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
        topRight: Radius.circular(30),
      ),
    ),
    child: TabBar(
      // indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(30),

      tabs: [
        Tab(
          child: Text(
            "data",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
        Tab(
          child: Text(
            "data",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```